# Update a column to same value for all rows in a group of the group by

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

| name | key | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | NULL |
| na2 | k2 | NULL |
| na3 | k1 | NULL |

If two or more rows have the same **`key`** value then I want to update the `uuid` value to the same uuid for those rows. If the key is unique then that row should have a unique uuid value.

Following is the desired outcome:

| name | key | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | 8274e89f-b119-4326-814d-4a864bbbe207 |
| na2 | k2 | 9a6c5f68-a3c2-4250-ac31-cc8c86a6440c |
| na3 | k1 | 8274e89f-b119-4326-814d-4a864bbbe207 |

Any ideas how to achieve this?

i have seen an example how its done for postgres but not sure how to convert that to mysql since very new with this.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289376/update-a-column-to-same-value-for-all-rows-in-a-group-of-the-group-by

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT key, GEN_RANDOM_UUID() uuid
              FROM test )
UPDATE test
SET uuid = cte.uuid
FROM cte
WHERE test.key = cte.key;
```

example of my dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/DXNMCZmU

Comment: `uuid()` is the equivalent of `GEN_RANDOM_UUID()` on mysql

Comment: yah i had tried just changing that but i seem to be still getting other errors. for example: ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cte
WHERE test.k = cte.k' at line 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
  select `key`, uuid() as uuid from test group by `key`
) 
update test join cte using (`key`)
set test.uuid = cte.uuid;
```

The multi-table UPDATE syntax you were using is for Microsoft SQL Server. MySQL uses different syntax. (Both are vendor-specific extensions to SQL, because ANSI SQL doesn't support multi-table UPDATE.)

Note that `key` is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), so you must delimit it to use it as an identifer.

Answer (score 1):

For older versions of mysql, you can do it using `inner join`

```
UPDATE test t
inner join (
   SELECT _key, uuid() as uuid
   FROM test 
   group by _key
) as cte on cte._key = t._key
SET t.uuid = cte.uuid
```

Demo here : https://dbfiddle.uk/VJxJR_IV